# SAP Hybris B2c 1905 Sample yacceleratorstorefront url not opening

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are looking to setup Build and Deployment pipeline for SAP Hybris B2c . We are able to build and deploy but we are not able to test the URL -> https://localhost:9002/yacceleratorstorefront . 
Is there any other sample development code that we could use and test the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use *site* parameter approach.

```
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=apparel-uk&clear=true
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=apparel-de&clear=true
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=electronics&clear=true
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=powertools&clear=true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute the following command to install and initialize the b2c accelerator

**In windows:**

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory\installer\>install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus -A local_property:initialpassword.admin=nimda && install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus initialize -A local_property:initialpassword.admin=nimda
```

**In Linux:**

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory/installer]./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus -A local_property:initialpassword.admin=nimda && ./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus initialize -A local_property:initialpassword.admin=nimda
```

2. Make the following entry in your hosts file:

   127.0.0.1   apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local electronics.local
3. Start the hybris server in any of the two ways:

**In windows:**

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory\installer\>install.bat -r b2c_acc_plus start
```

or

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory\hybris\bin\platform\>hybrisserver.bat
```

**In Linux:**

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory/installer]./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus start
```

or

```
Your_hybris_installation_directory/hybris/bin/platform]./hybrisserver.sh
```

**Once your hybris server is running**, you can access any of the following URLs:

1. http://electronics.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
2. http://apparel-uk.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
3. http://apparel-de.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/

Comment: b2c_acc receipe is removed from 1905 version.